# How to call a method on .mm file from a objective c class

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, methods

I am working on an iphone app. I need to call a method on a .mm file. Here is simplified version of the problem:

**ViewHelper.h**

```
- (void)testMtd;
```

**ViewHelper.mm**  (notice this is .mm)

```
- (void)testMtd{
   NSLog(@"Call reached mm");
}
```

**SomeViewController.m**  (import to ViewHelper.h omitted for clarity)

```
- (void)someCallerMtd{
   NSLog(@"before");
   [viewHelper testMtd]; //call does not work
   NSLog(@"after");
}
```

I see "before" and "after" in the log, but "Call reached mm" never gets printed. Are there special rules to call obj c methods in a .mm file? What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you declare and initialize `viewHelper`?

Comment: Another note, if you write your class inside a **.mm** file, it still remains a normal Objective-C class. The only thing that changes is that you can call c++ code inside the **.mm** file.

Comment: @sch Yes I missed the init part! Thanks for the pointer and clarification reg .mm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it has nothing to do with `.mm` file, it is still objective-c clss. Second, Your mistake is not allocating `ViewHelper`.

The solutions is either alloc your `ViewHelper` or make `(void)testMtd` publicly. depend on what your need.

either change your `SomeViewController.m`:

```
- (void)someCallerMtd{
   NSLog(@"before");
   viewHelper = [[ViewHelper alloc] init];
   [viewHelper testMtd]; 
   [viewHelper release];
   NSLog(@"after");
}
```

or change your `ViewHelper` :

```
//ViewHelper.h
+ (void)testMtd;

//ViewHelper.mm
+ (void)testMtd{
   NSLog(@"Call reached mm");
}

- (void)someCallerMtd{
       NSLog(@"before");
       [ViewHelper testMtd]; //remember to use ViewHelper class. not viewhelper.
       NSLog(@"after");
    }
```

Comment: It was like 3.30am when I posted the question, but gosh how did I miss that!! Thanks for the answer HelmiB.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reasons that your `-testMtd` method never gets called is that `viewHelper` is nil. Make sure that it points to a valid instance of the ViewHelper class. It's legal in Objective-C to send a message to a nil pointer, but no method will be called in that case.